# Using groupby or pivot_tables to transform a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by, pivot-table

I have a dataframe that consists of timestamps (per hour) that should be grouped by every 5 rows, with the amount of rain per hour. The problem in this situation is that some timestamps that should be grouped together have different dates as some timestamps go over midnight. My Original `df`:

```
           Datum            HH  DayPrecipitation
9137    2016-01-16 18:00:00 18  0
9138    2016-01-16 19:00:00 19  6
9139    2016-01-16 20:00:00 20  0
...         ...             ... ...
44874   2020-02-13 19:00:00 19  0
44875   2020-02-13 20:00:00 20  0
44878   2020-02-13 23:00:00 23  0
```

I would like to have this in a wide format looking something like this:

Where timestamp 1-5 are every 5 rows of the previous and the values come from `df['DayPrecipitation']`

```
       Datum               timestamp1   timestamp2 ... timestamp 5
    2016-01-16                  0            6              0
    2020-02-13                  0            0              0
```

I'm not sure how to go about this as grouping by date won't give me the results I need but I don't know to groupby every 5 rows.
Help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would first resample the dataframe at a `'5H'` frequency. Then add 2 columns: one for the date, and one for the timestamp which is the hour divided (integer division) by 5. From that point a `pivot` will give the expected dataframe.

I assume here that the `Datum` column contains true timestamp. If it contains other type, you will have to change it with `df['Datum'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datum'])`. Code could be:

```
df5 = df[['Datum', 'DayPrecipitation']].resample('5H', on='Datum').sum().reset_index()
df5['timestamp'] = df5['Datum'].dt.hour // 5
df5['Datum'] = df5['Datum'].dt.date
resul = df5.pivot('Datum', 'timestamp', 'DayPrecipitation')
```

But every 5th day will have only 4 timestamps, so the 5th one will be a `NaN` value.